# how to echo doctype, set in application.ini, in zend framework view

Tags: zend-framework, doctype

In my Zend Framework application I want to echo the doctype in my view layout with:

```
<?= $this->doctype() . "\n"; ?>
```

I have the following lines in my application.ini:

```
resources.view[] =
resources.view.doctype = "HTML5"
resources.view.charset = "UTF-8"
```

which gives me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

apparently the settings in the application.ini are ignored and instead the default doctype is used.

Is there a way to echo the doctype in my view / layout without using the bootstrap (I know that works but I do not want to have my settings scattered over application.ini and bootstrap)?

Comment: Do you need the line `resources.view[] =`?  I don't know if that might be causing a problem?

Comment: @ChrisAnstey No, I do not need it, deleted it, but it does not cause the problem

Answer (score 3):

you need to configure your view in bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initView()
{
    // Initialize view
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->doctype('XHTML1_TRANSITIONAL');
    $view->setEncoding('UTF-8');//per , htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

    $view->headTitle('ABC');


    // Add it to the ViewRenderer
    $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    // Return it, so that it can be stored by the bootstrap
    return $view;
}
```

then use in the layout or some view

```
echo $this->doctype();
```

Comment: Thx, ashamed to say ... I was editing an application.ini of another app, see my answer below